# Use Logback access with Grails 3 webapp (Springboot) application deployed with java -jar

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, logback, grails-3.1

How do I configure grails 3 which uses logback as the default logging framework to log `HTTP`requests of the embedded tomcat just like the tomcat application server does in creating a log-access log file?

I know I have to use the [logback access](http://logback.qos.ch/access.html) module, but it is stated that it works with deployment containers such as tomcat and jetty

Answer (score 1):

My Grails 3 app was using the following dependency:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat
```

A quick search led me to: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html

So my application.yml file now contains a block like below:

```
server:
    tomcat:
        basedir: '.'
        accesslog:
            enabled: true
            pattern: '%t %a %u "%r" %s (%D ms)'
```